# How to split of a string with regex

Tags: java, regex

```
public String replace(){
    String[] parts = str.split("&([A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+|x[A-Fa-f0-9]+);");
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(parts[i]);

    }
    return "";
}
```

what makes this line exactly "String[] parts = str.split("&([A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+|x[A-Fa-f0-9]+);");"? i tried in my code but it didnt do anything..could someone give a string example so i can see how it splits ?

Comment: `&lt;text1&gt;&lt;text2&gt;`

Comment: There are tons of sites like http://www.myregextester.com/ where you can throw all kinds of strings at interactively

Comment: Looks more like XML/HTML entities, hence the leading `&` and trailing `;`

Comment: Where is the variable ``str`` defined?

Comment: The [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) has a list of online regex testers, listed by flavor (at the bottom). Debuggex and regex101 are what I use. regex101 also a has a replacement tester. Offline I use Regex Buddy.

Comment: can you post an example of a subject String ?

Comment: @Tuga, I think he is asking for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one example of a string that will be split by the `regex` you provided.

```
import java.util.regex.*;


public class ReverseRegex{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "hello &fjeaifjiajwta; world";
        String[] parts = str.split("&([A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+|x[A-Fa-f0-9]+);");
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(parts[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are a few more examples.

```
    String str = "hello &21342352352; world"; // Two pieces
    String str = "hello &xffea424242; world"; // Two pieces
    String str = "hello &xffea424242; world &hefiajeifjae; world"; // Three pieces.
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex is apparently for a named or numbered HTML entity reference, but it's incomplete.  It's missing the hash sign for the numbered entities and it doesn't allow for names with digits in them, like `&sup2;` and `&frac14;`.  Here's what I would use:

```
"&(?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*|#[0-9]+|#x[0-9a-fA-F]+);"
```

However, I don't see why you would want to use that regex with `split()`, which throws away whatever it matches and returns everything else.  If you want to do something with the entities themselves, you'll most likely want to use `find()`.  Here's an example that just collects the entities in a list;

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("&(?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*|#[0-9]+|#x[0-9a-fA-F]+);");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    matchList.add(m.group());
}
```

Comment: i m just trying to figure out how to replace [ä,ü,ö] ina a string with HTML_escapecodes...but it needs to be really a fast change.. not every char in the string needs to be looked for it..